# SPARK_RPC_CLIENT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT in running Hive On Spark - YARN Cluster mode

Tags: apache-spark, hive, hadoop-yarn

I am using HDP2.3 and trying to use Spark(1.3.1) as the execution engine for running hive queries.
spark-assembly jar is also available in the hive/lib folder.

I am able to run the query in spark-master: local but facing the below issue when using spark-master: yarn-cluster.

command run,

> hive -e "set hive.execution.engine=spark; set
>   spark.master=yarn-cluster;  select count(*) from db_name.table_name;"

output,

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/hdp/2.3.0.0-2557/hadoop/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/hdp/2.3.0.0-2557/hive/lib/spark-assembly-1.3.1-hadoop2.6.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/root/downloads/machine/spark/lib/spark-assembly-1.3.1-hadoop2.6.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
WARNING: Use "yarn jar" to launch YARN applications.
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/hdp/2.3.0.0-2557/hadoop/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/hdp/2.3.0.0-2557/hive/lib/spark-assembly-1.3.1-hadoop2.6.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/root/downloads/machine/spark/lib/spark-assembly-1.3.1-hadoop2.6.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]

Logging initialized using configuration in file:/etc/hive/2.3.0.0-2557/0/hive-log4j.properties
Query ID = root_20150909201120_a67d5ca3-36df-43fe-894a-3645585eec7a
Total jobs = 1
Launching Job 1 out of 1
In order to change the average load for a reducer (in bytes):
  set hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer=<number>
In order to limit the maximum number of reducers:
  set hive.exec.reducers.max=<number>
In order to set a constant number of reducers:
  set mapreduce.job.reduces=<number>
Failed to execute spark task, with exception 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException(Failed to create spark client.)'
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.spark.SparkTask
```

yarn log of the application,

```
15/09/09 19:42:27 INFO yarn.ApplicationMaster: Waiting for spark context initialization ...
15/09/09 19:42:27 INFO client.RemoteDriver: Connecting to: sandbox.hortonworks.com:59941
15/09/09 19:42:27 ERROR yarn.ApplicationMaster: User class threw exception: SPARK_RPC_CLIENT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: SPARK_RPC_CLIENT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT
        at org.apache.hive.spark.client.rpc.RpcConfiguration.<clinit>(RpcConfiguration.java:46)
        at org.apache.hive.spark.client.RemoteDriver.<init>(RemoteDriver.java:146)
        at org.apache.hive.spark.client.RemoteDriver.main(RemoteDriver.java:556)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$2.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:480)
15/09/09 19:42:27 INFO yarn.ApplicationMaster: Final app status: FAILED, exitCode: 15, (reason: User class threw exception: SPARK_RPC_CLIENT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT)
15/09/09 19:42:37 ERROR yarn.ApplicationMaster: SparkContext did not initialize after waiting for 100000 ms. Please check earlier log output for errors. Failing the application.
15/09/09 19:42:37 INFO yarn.ApplicationMaster: Unregistering ApplicationMaster with FAILED (diag message: User class threw exception: SPARK_RPC_CLIENT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT)
15/09/09 19:42:37 INFO yarn.ApplicationMaster: Deleting staging directory .sparkStaging/application_1441817597849_0008
```

Any help on debugging the issue is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think queries can be executed in yarn-cluster mode.

You can run interactive queries in local and yarn-client mode only